# How To Have An OGG Video Perform Auto-Playback In Firefox 3.6.20

Tags: html, firefox, video

I have a simple HTML5 oriented local page, that can correctly and consistently playback a simple video loop using MP4 and WebM formats correctly under Windows Vista and Windows 7 using IE 9 and Google Chrome 13.  Under FireFox 3.6.20, the designated OGG Video file will play, but once completed, will not go back to the beginning of the video clip and play again.

My HTML for performing the video playback is as follows:

```
<video class="video-js" width="600" height="400" poster="images/home.jpg" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"> 
  <source src="videos/home.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' /> 
  <source src="videos/home.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> 
  <source src="videos/home.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' /> 
  <!-- Flash Fallback. Use any flash video player here. Make sure to keep the vjs-flash-fallback class. --> 
  <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="600" height="400" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" /> 
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
    <param name="flashvars" 
      value='config={"playlist":["image.png", {"url": "home.mp4","autoPlay":true,"autoBuffering":true}]}' /> 
    <!-- Image Fallback. Typically the same as the poster image. --> 
    <img src="images/home.jpg" width="600" height="400" alt="Poster Image" 
      title="No video playback capabilities." /> 
  </object> 
</video>
```

Is there a way that I can have FireFox go back to the beginning of a video, home.ogv, and resume playing once it has finished its initial playback?

My apologies if this might be a duplicate question, but I've tried to narrow down my HTML the replicate the auto-playback issue as much as I could, and none of the other solutions posted on the recommended subjects seemed to get me closer to a working solution.

Thank you in advance for your time, help and patience...

Answer (score 0):

Loop attribute won't work, you'll need some JS workaround. You could just use [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) or maybe [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-html5) and let it work it out for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions.  I've already tried a posted workaround in JavaScript, as posted at http://blog.joggink.com/2010/10/cheap-jquery-fix-for-the-firefox-video-loop-problem/.  I tried the non-JQuery implementation that follows:
    
document.querySelectorAll('video[video-js]').onended = function() 
{
    this.play();
};  

JavaScript's querySelectAll() should return the video element from the page, and once the end of the video has been reached, this.play() should result in the video repeating the playback from the beginning.  However, this did not happen as expected.

Comment: [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) says it supports Firefox 3.6. It uses `addEventListener("ended"...` with some browser-dependent quirks. For Firefox, id does `self.htmlElement.media.currentTime = 0;`. I think you'd best read some of its code.